# How to remove the item you click on from the Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ecmascript-6

I have created banks displayed from the database in the form of cards.
How can I take the id of the document I click on and delete this card from the database?

```js
function getBanks() {
  db.collection("banks").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let banks = [];
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
      const bank = change.doc.data();
      if (change.type === "added") {
        banks.push(bank);
        generateBanks([bank]);
      } else if (change.type === "removed") {
        console.log("Removed bank: ", bank );
      }
    });
  });
}

function generateBanks(banks) {
  banks.forEach((bank) => {
    ...
    const bank_delete_el = document.createElement("button");
    bank_delete_el.classList.add("delete");
    bank_delete_el.innerText = "Delete";

    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example using click event listener and firebase `delete`:

```
function generateBanks(banks) {
  banks.forEach((bank) => {
    ...
    const bank_delete_el = document.createElement("button");
    bank_delete_el.classList.add("delete");
    bank_delete_el.innerText = "Delete";

    bank_delete_el.addEventListener("click", (_event) => {
      console.log("Deleting bank...", bank);
      db.collection("banks").doc(bank.id).delete()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Bank successfully deleted!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error removing Bank: ", error);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Here are the docs for [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and firebase [delete documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#delete_documents).

> Also it looks like your `docChanges` body is missing the `id` field for new banks, whitch is required for deletion.

```
const bank = change.doc.data();
// Should be 
const bank = {
  id: change.doc.id,
  ...change.doc.data(),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `id` of the document as a `data-attribute`, eg:

```js
function generateBanks(banks) {
  banks.forEach((bank) => {
    ...
    const bank_delete_el = document.createElement("button");
    benk_delete_el.setAttribute("bank-id", bank.id); // add the id as data attribute
    bank_delete_el.classList.add("delete");
    bank_delete_el.innerText = "Delete";

    });
  });
}
```

This will create the button as

```html
<button class="delete" data-bank-id="some-id-123">
  Delete
</button>
```

Then when you click the delete button you can get the id and delete it from firestore

```js
// on click -> get button element, then
const bankId = myButton.getAttribute("bank-id");

db.collection("banks").doc(bankId).delete().then(() => {
    // ...
});
```